# CGRectMake. Is Unavailable In Swift

Tags: c#, swift, xcode

can someone help me here I am currently getting this error saying that CGRectMake is not available in Swift. I have looked at other answers on this and I am still getting a little confused. Could anyone please write me an exact answer would be much appreciated.

```
 scrollView.frame = CGRect(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
```

Answer (score 42):

CGRectMake has been deprecated. The syntax is now just CGRect. I believe the syntax change was introduced in Swift 3.

Notice that the x and y together form a CGPoint, and the width and height form a CGSize. So when you say:

```
scrollView.frame = CGRect(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
```

you are putting the scrollView at the CGPoint (0,0) and giving it the same  same CGSize as the width and height of the view (covering the whole view).

Comment: using like this:
CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

Answer (score 7):

Which Swift version are you using? I think you are using Swift 3 and above.

CGRectMake is deprecated after Swift 3. You have to use CGRect instead of CGRectMake.

```
     let scrollView = UIScrollView()

     scrollView.frame = CGRect(0,0,self.view.frame.width,self.view.frame.height)
```

Comment: I am using the latest swift 3 and thank you for your answers I am trying these today and I will let you now what worked for me much appreciated.